# Disable host key checking for HDFS?

Tags: hadoop, ssl, hdfs

I am trying to spin up a simple HDFS cluster on a single host. When I run the `start-dfs.sh` script to start my namenode and datanodes I see the following in the console: `The authenticity of host 'localhost (127.0.0.1)' can't be established.`. Typically, for a local development deployment such as this I would simply disable host key checking, but I have searched through the [HDFS configuration properties](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.4.1/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/hdfs-default.xml) and I can't find such an option. How I can disable strict host key checking for my single host HDFS deployment?

Comment: Wouldnt that be a SSH config? Not sure what this has to do with Hadoop

Comment: But *for Hadoop*, you need to ensure the SSH key, even locally, is added into `authorized_keys` file

Comment: Whoops, I didn't cop that the script was using SSH underneath. Silly question. Thanks for the pointer.